Tectonic: Generate PDF ignoring Errors
For the life of me I can't find how to have tectonic keep going and produce a pdf file despite the errors.
Suppose I'm running tectonic main.tex so that I can produce a pdf output from it.
I generally aim to fix the errors but sometimes I just need it to produce an output pdf. Is it possible to get this without having to fallback to pdflatex?

after an error the pdf output is not reliable. It could miss text or contain faulty text and even produce invalid pdf and more. So correct the error.

If tectonic stops similar to other LaTeX programs, e.g. like this:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \error
            the early 1810s, he met with Napoleon Bonaparte in Elba....

? ?
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
?

you might be able to hit "s" to scroll for further error messages until the end, and maybe (but there's no guarantee) you'll get a faulty PDF.

Please never do ignore error messages! Solve each error before printing the PDF!

Hi Mensch, I completely agree with you, but as @ixvc sounded desperate to produce a "best effort" solution in spite of errors, I thought this answer might still help him/her. I did not intend to promote bad manners.

Sometimes the "I" option allows the insertion of some as {\huge ERROR} and continues, producing finally a PDF, and that could help identify the exact place of the issue without opening the log file.
